# I want to save data in SecondActivity from FirstActivity using Room

Tags: android

I have three activities, I capture all data but one from DetailActivity upon button click and save in database using Room; My intention is to insert all these data into the database and start ReviewActivity so as to get the arraylist of reviews and also insert it in the database. Everything seems to work fine until when I want to view review offline because I believe it has been saved, reviews does not get loaded.
This is my DetailActivity,

```
    TextView overview_tv;    ImageView image_tv;    TextView name_tv;    TextView ratings;    Context context;    TextView release_date;    ImageView backdrop_poster;    private ExpandableHeightListView trailers;    public static ArrayList<Youtube> youtube;    public static ArrayList<Review> reviews;    TrailerViewAdapter adapter;    public static DataObject data;    DataObject dataObject;    ArrayList<Review> savedReview;    private static final String IMAGE_URL = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/";    private static final String THE_MOVIEDB_URL2 = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/";    private static final String MOVIE_QUERY2 = "api_key";    private static final String API_KEY2 = "6cc4f47bd4a64e0117e157b79072ae37";    private static String SEARCH_QUERY2 = "videos";    public static int movieId;    Button viewReviews;    Button favourite;    String movieRating;    private static final int YOUTUBE_SEARCH_LOADER = 23;    private static final int REVIEW_SEARCH_LOADER = 24;    File file;    String name;    String overview;    String releaseDate;    int switcher;    public static ArrayList<Review> favouriteReviews;    TextView trev;    AppDatabase mDb;    //Navigation arrow on the action bar    @Override    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {        int id = item.getItemId();        if (id == android.R.id.home) {            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);        }        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);    }    @Override    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);        mDb = AppDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext());        youtube = new ArrayList<Youtube>();        reviews = new ArrayList<Review>();        adapter = new TrailerViewAdapter(this, youtube);        //Credit to Paolorotolo @github        trailers = findViewById(R.id.expandable_list);        trailers.setAdapter(adapter);        trailers.setExpanded(true);        //Navigation arrow on the acton bar; check also override onOptionsItemSelected        ActionBar actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();        if (actionBar != null) {            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);        }        context = getApplicationContext();        Intent intent = getIntent();        if (intent == null) {            closeOnError();        }        switcher = getIntent().getIntExtra("switch", 3);        overview_tv = findViewById(R.id.overview);        image_tv = findViewById(R.id.image);        name_tv = findViewById(R.id.name);        ratings = findViewById(R.id.ratings);        release_date = findViewById(R.id.release_date);        backdrop_poster = findViewById(R.id.backdrop_poster);        trev = findViewById(R.id.review_show);        viewReviews = findViewById(R.id.review_button);        favourite = findViewById(R.id.favourite_button);        addListenerOnRatingBar(ratings);        if (switcher != 2) {            favourite.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);            dataObject = (DataObject) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("array");            final String favouriteName = dataObject.getName();            final String favouriteOverview = dataObject.getOverview();            final String favouriteReleaseDate = dataObject.getReleaseDate();            ArrayList<Youtube> savedTrailer = dataObject.getTrailers();            savedReview = dataObject.getMovieReviews();            movieRating = dataObject.getRating();            name_tv.setText(favouriteName);            overview_tv.setText(favouriteOverview);            ratings.setText("Rating: " + movieRating);            release_date.setText("Release Date: " + favouriteReleaseDate);//            Toast.makeText(this, "Testing Reviews " + savedReview.get(0).getAuthor(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            String imagePath = name_tv.getText().toString() + "0i";            String backdropPath = name_tv.getText().toString() + "1b";            try {                DataObjectAdapter.downloadImage(imagePath, image_tv, this);            } catch (Exception e) {                e.printStackTrace();            }            try {                DataObjectAdapter.downloadImage(backdropPath, backdrop_poster, context);            } catch (Exception e) {                e.printStackTrace();            }            if (savedTrailer != null) {                TrailerViewAdapter lv = new TrailerViewAdapter(DetailActivity.this, savedTrailer);                trailers.setAdapter(lv);                switcher = 3;            }        } else {            name = getIntent().getStringExtra("Name");            overview = getIntent().getStringExtra("Overview");            final String image = getIntent().getStringExtra("Image");            movieId = getIntent().getIntExtra("movieId", 1);            final String backdrop = getIntent().getStringExtra("backdrop");            releaseDate = getIntent().getStringExtra("releaseDate");            movieRating = getIntent().getStringExtra("rating");            Log.i("this", "switch " + switcher);            name_tv.setText(name);            overview_tv.setText(overview);            ratings.setText("Rating: " + movieRating);            release_date.setText("Release Date: " + releaseDate);            //load backdrop poster            Picasso.with(context)                    .load(IMAGE_URL + backdrop)                    .fit()                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)                    .error(R.drawable.placeholder_image)                    .into(backdrop_poster);            Picasso.with(context)                    .load(IMAGE_URL + image)                    .fit()                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)                    .error(R.drawable.placeholder_image)                    .into(image_tv);            getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(YOUTUBE_SEARCH_LOADER, null, this);            //getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(REVIEW_SEARCH_LOADER, null, this);            //loadTrailers();            //loadReviews();            //populateKeys();        }        /**         * Here manages the views(list) for reviews         */        viewReviews.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                                           @Override                                           public void onClick(View v) {                                               if (switcher == 3) {                                                   startActivity(new Intent(DetailActivity.this,                                                           ReviewActivity.class)                                                           .putExtra("switch", 3));                                               } else {                                                   Log.i("this", "I am from initial" + switcher);                                                   startActivity(new Intent(DetailActivity.this,                                                           ReviewActivity.class).putExtra("id", movieId));                                               }                                           }                                       }        );        favourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                                         @Override                                         public void onClick(View v) {                                             data = new DataObject();                                             data.setName(name);                                             data.setOverview(overview);                                             data.setRating(movieRating);                                             data.setReleaseDate(releaseDate);                                             data.setTrailers(youtube);//                                             data.setMovieReviews(reviews);                                             try {                                                 saveImage(name_tv.getText().toString() + "0i", image_tv);                                                 saveImage(name_tv.getText().toString() + "1b", backdrop_poster);                                             } catch (IOException e) {                                                 e.printStackTrace();                                             }                                             Toast.makeText(context,                                                     "The movie is saved as a favourite",                                                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                             AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {                                                 @Override                                                 public void run() {                                                     mDb.dataDao().insertData(data);                                                 }                                             });                                             startActivity(new Intent(DetailActivity.this,                                                     ReviewActivity.class).putExtra("id", movieId)                                                     .putExtra(ReviewActivity.EXTRA_DATA_ID, 20));                                         }                                     }        );    }
```

And my ReviewActivity

```
public class ReviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<Review>>{    public static ArrayList<Review>  reviews;    public static List<DataObject> favouriteReviews;    public static RecyclerView reviewList;    ArrayList<Review> r;    private static final int REVIEW_SEARCH_LOADER = 24;    private static final String MOVIE_QUERY3 = "api_key";    private static final String API_KEY3 = "6cc4f47bd4a64e0117e157b79072ae37";    private static String SEARCH_QUERY3 = "reviews";    private static final String THE_MOVIEDB_URL3 = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/";    private static int movId;    public static final String EXTRA_DATA_ID = "extraDataId";    private static final int DEFAULT_TASK_ID = -1;    private int mTaskId = DEFAULT_TASK_ID;    DataObject data1;    AppDatabase mDb;    ReviewAdapter revAdapter;    int loaderSwitch;    @Override    protected void onResume() {        super.onResume();    }    @Override    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        setContentView(R.layout.activity_review);        mDb = AppDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext());        reviews = new ArrayList<Review>();        favouriteReviews = new ArrayList<DataObject>();        reviewList = findViewById(R.id.review_list);        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());        reviewList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);        reviewList.setHasFixedSize(true);        int switcher = getIntent().getIntExtra("switch", 1);        Intent intent = getIntent();        if (intent == null) {            finish();        }        Log.i("this", "swithcer " + switcher);        Log.i("this loader", "Loader " + loaderSwitch);        if (switcher == 3){            DataObject dataObject = (DataObject) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("ArrayOfReviews");            if (dataObject != null){                ArrayList<Review> movieReviews = dataObject.getMovieReviews();                Toast.makeText(this, "There are reviews saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                revAdapter = new ReviewAdapter(this, movieReviews );                reviewList.setAdapter(revAdapter);            }        } else         {            movId = getIntent().getIntExtra("id", 20);            revAdapter = new ReviewAdapter(this, reviews);            reviewList.setAdapter(revAdapter);            loadReviews();            //populateReview();        }        DividerItemDecoration decoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this, VERTICAL);        reviewList.addItemDecoration(decoration);    }    @Override    protected void onStart() {        super.onStart();        //loadReviews();    }    public static URL buildUrl3(String stringUrl) {        Uri uri = Uri.parse(THE_MOVIEDB_URL3).buildUpon()                .appendPath(stringUrl)                .appendPath(SEARCH_QUERY3)                .appendQueryParameter(MOVIE_QUERY3, API_KEY3)                .build();        URL url = null;        try {            url = new URL(uri.toString());        } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {            Log.e(TAG, "Error creating URL", exception);        }        return url;    }    public void loadReviews(){        // COMPLETED (19) Create a bundle called queryBundle        Bundle queryBundle = new Bundle();        // COMPLETED (20) Use putString with SEARCH_QUERY_URL_EXTRA as the key and the String value of the URL as the value//        queryBundle.putString(SEARCH_QUERY_URL_EXTRA, url.toString());        // COMPLETED (21) Call getSupportLoaderManager and store it in a LoaderManager variable        LoaderManager loaderManager = getSupportLoaderManager();        // COMPLETED (22) Get our Loader by calling getLoader and passing the ID we specified        Loader<ArrayList<Review>> movieReviews = loaderManager.getLoader(REVIEW_SEARCH_LOADER);        // COMPLETED (23) If the Loader was null, initialize it. Else, restart it.        if (movieReviews == null) {            loaderManager.initLoader(REVIEW_SEARCH_LOADER, queryBundle, this);        } else {            loaderManager.restartLoader(REVIEW_SEARCH_LOADER, queryBundle, this);        }    }    @Override    public Loader<ArrayList<Review>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {        return new AsyncTaskLoader<ArrayList<Review>>(this) {            @Override            protected void onStartLoading() {                super.onStartLoading();                forceLoad();            }            @Override            public ArrayList<Review> loadInBackground() {                String g = String.valueOf(movId);                // Create URL object                URL url = buildUrl3(g);                // Perform HTTP request on the URL and receive a JSON response back                String jsonResponse = "";                try {                    jsonResponse = getResponseFromHttpUrl(url);                } catch (Exception e) {                    e.printStackTrace();                }                reviews = MovieJsonUtils.parseReview(jsonResponse);                return reviews;            }        };    }    @Override    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<Review>> loader, ArrayList<Review> dat) {        if (reviews != null) {            Intent intent = getIntent();            if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_DATA_ID)) {                //mButton.setText(R.string.update_button);                if (mTaskId == DEFAULT_TASK_ID) {                    mTaskId = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_DATA_ID, DEFAULT_TASK_ID);                    AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {                        @Override                        public void run() {                            data.setMovieReviews(reviews);                            mDb.dataDao().updateData(data);                            //mDb.dataDao().insertData(data);                            final List<DataObject> task = mDb.dataDao().loadById(mTaskId);                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {                                @Override                                public void run() {                                    populateUI(task);                                }                            });                        }                    });                }            } else {                ReviewAdapter lv = new ReviewAdapter(ReviewActivity.this, reviews);                reviewList.setAdapter(lv);            }        }    }    @Override    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<Review>> loader) {    }
```

Data gets loaded from MainActivity, the saved data is passed on to other activities as a parcellable bundle via intent, the passed data is displayed in DetailActivity but not in ReviewActivity.

Alternatively, if I can load reviews alongside YouTube keys from DetailActivity, I believe I can handle the database issue from there, but two Loaders wouldn't just work together, the app crashes; I am aware two AsyncTasks concurrently run together solved this problem, but I prefer to use Loaders because of performance on configuration change

Comment: Please read documentation about [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)

Comment: how can i read your single line code? -_-a